# ember.js handlebar - using variables inside action helper

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I am trying to create dynamic menu for a cms. I have action and target variables stored in database and I want to pass those to action helper:

```
<li><a href="#" {{action this.action target=this.controllername}}>{{unbound this.name}}</a></li>
```

I wrote the above code and I am getting the following error on console:

target[actionName] is undefined

return target[actionName].call(target, event);

Kindly let me know what is the right way to do this.

Regards,
Karthik

Comment: Can you provide a jsFiddle example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: @ebryn I had forgotten to indent the code. Now I have edited the question and the code is visible. And I do not know jsFiddle. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think in this jsfiddle you find the answer to your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/Malkyne/ydTWZ/

```
{{#each item in content}}
    <li>
        <a {{action select item}} {{bindAttr class = "item.classNames"}}> 
            {{item.label}}
        </a>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```